# CodeIgniter session gets modified automatically during page load

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I am currently working on a CodeIgniter (v 3.1.9) project. It has a login page.

When two different users (A and B) try to login from two different systems at same time, one of the user's session gets modified on loading.

The loading takes a small amount of time and if the user A gets logged in first, it will be redirected to its own user homepage. Next, when user B completes its login, it will be redirected to user A's homepage which is strange. I also noticed that user B gets user A's session ID here. The same issue happens if the order of user login is changed, i.e if user B gets logged in first. The issue is noticed only when two users click the login button at the same time, otherwise it is fine.

Below is the configuration used for my website.

// config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH.'sess/cache/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Below codes are used for creating session and destroying it after login/logout.

// Create session after login

```
$this->session->set_userdata('employer_id', $data['id']);
```

// Destory session after logout

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('employer_id');
```

Is it due to a bug related with CodeIgniter. Are there any workarounds to fix this issue?

Comment: most likely you've a bug in your application - because Codeigniter is a pretty foolproofed system. but without showing us your code its pretty unlikely you would get help here.

Comment: i'm not sure what auth system you are using - in house or otherwise (i can recommend ion auth). but without a full audit of your app this seems a bit too broad. i understand that you might be looking for a ci bug, but if such a massive session issue were the case the devs would have fixed it by now (ci is one of the oldest actively maintained frameworks).

Comment: I have edited and included some of the codes for more clarity.

Comment: Show full login function ? TBH I'm not sure anything will help here. Sounds like a strange case  that would require someone to look through the code and do multiple tests.